# UIPicker reloading content

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

i have a problem with UIPicker, im keeping my Picker in Navigation controller. i want the Picker content to reload whenever the navigation controller push the PickerView.

but the pickerview content maintaining same state in all navigation.. how to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question you might want to look at http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006842-CH3-SW10

Reloading the View Picker

```
– reloadAllComponents
– reloadComponent:
```